# Add custom nodes in firebase using Node-RED

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, raspberry-pi3, node-red

I am new to Raspberry Pi and Node-RED. I am want to add custom node to firebase using Node-RED nodes. Here is my database screenshot :

[image]

I have used push option of firebase node to create multiple nodes with auto generated ID's. I want to give custom ID like "User1", "User2" and so on using firebase node in Node-RED. How can this be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

`push()` always generates random IDs.  The names of these nodes can't be changed after they're added.  If you want to assign your own names, you will need to build a path to the node you want, and populate it with `set()`.

Comment: Yes, this worked for me and I realized the difference. Thank you for the help